# Android Webview href link not working

Tags: android, webview, href

Basically, I have a Webview that points to an internal *"note.html"* file.

In this *note.html* file, which is written in HTML, I have a website `HREF`, but when I click on it on a device, I get an error message:

```
"the webpage at file:///android/asset/www.blahblah.com might be temporarily down ...etc."
```

I am somewhat aware that I have to parse the URL or something of that nature, and would really appreciate a response on how to get the `HREF` link to open the proper web link to a browser.

**the variable:** 
private static final String tip_URL = "file:///android_asset/tip.html";

**the onCreate:**
WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); mywebview.loadUrl(tip_URL);

this works fine on a mobile device, however, in the tip.html there is a link to a website, and when clicked i want a browser to open to go to that site..it is not another local page..

Comment: Do you know the path of the html page that you are reffering... Show the code.

Comment: the html page works fine, its the href link in the page that does not open the proper link....

Comment: i am asking whether you are putting the correct path of html page ....and assuming that html page is fine....and asking for your android code,,,,

Comment: This works fine, however, in the actual tip.html, there is a HREF weblink, but when i click the link on a device i get an error...please help

Comment: one thing above comments could be written by editing your question... and assuming the next page would be in the same folder ... you just have to give the name of that page in href... I think when you write www. blah.com then it searches on the internet....